# How to intercept errors in E4 RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an e4 application, and I want to handle how all errors are shown to the user.

I overrode `WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException`, and that works for some things.  But since upgrading to E4, I've been getting error dialogs like this:

[image: An internal error occurred during: "Workbench Auto-Save Background Job"]

How do I intercept these errors?

Comment: Not sure, maybe with the osgi event system if there is a topic for all these Errors

Comment: e4 does not use `WorkbenchAdvisor`. Are you sure this is pure e4 or is it an Eclipse 4 application using the 3.x compatibility layer.

Comment: Eclipse 4 application using the 3.x compatibility layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Eclipse 4 added a method to the WorkbenchAdvisor](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_statushandling_defining.htm).

```
@Override 
public AbstractStatusHandler getWorkbenchErrorHandler() {
    AbstractStatusHandler handler = new AbstractStatusHandler() {
        /** We want to handle all errors. */
        @Override
        public boolean supportsNotification(int type) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(StatusAdapter statusAdapter, int style) {
             // do something useful
        }
    };
    return handler;
}
```